# Sum of pandas DataFrame in a dict with Xarray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray

I would like to know if there is an elegant way to sum pd.DataFrame with exact same indexes and column using the Xarray package.

## The problem

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(123)
pdts = pd.Index(["AAPL", "GOOG", "FB"], name="RIC")
dates = pd.date_range("20200601", "20200620", name="Date")
field_A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(dates.size, pdts.size), index=dates, columns=pdts)
field_B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(dates.size, pdts.size), index=dates, columns=pdts)
field_C = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(dates.size, pdts.size), index=dates, columns=pdts)
df_dict = {
    "A": field_A,
    "B": field_B,
    "C": field_C,
}
```

What I would like to obtain is the `res = df_dict["A"] + df_dict["B"] + df_dict["C"]` using the Xarray package, which I just started learning. I know there are solutions using Pandas like:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((dates.size, pdts.size)), index=dates, columns=pdts)
for k, v in df_dict.items():
    res += v
```

## Attempts

What I have tried in Xarray :

As the Dataset class looked like a dict of datas, I thought the most straightforward option would be this :

```
ds = xr.Dataset(df_dict)
```

However when performing `ds.sum()` it won't allow me to sum along the different data variables, the result is either sum over "Date" or sum over "RIC" or over both, but performed for each data variable.

Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a way to do it is `ds.to_array().sum("variable")`